# Visual Studio version-agnostic projects/solutions: is it possible?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, versioning, projects-and-solutions

I remember seeing an open source project within the last year that I was able to open in both VS 2008 and VS 2010 without an upgrade wizard popping up.  I think...

Is it possible to create a project/solution that will open up in any version of Visual Studio without prompting me to run the upgrade wizard?  If so, how do I do this?

Information for both C++ and C# projects would be most helpful.

Comment: Do you have the upgrade wizard if you create a project with VS 2010, then open it in VS 2008?

Comment: I think I've seen projects that will generate both 2008 and 2010 versions from some other sort of makefile / project description, but I'm fairly sure you can't use the same project files in both.

Comment: The question is about C# and C++ projects in VS, and I would really like to know if it would be possible, including changing VS settings. Also, I would be OK with limitations such as lower .NET version would be OK.

Comment: @Otiel: When opening a VS2010 authored solution in VS2008, I get an error message.  Is says that it is a valid solution file, but it was created with a newer version so it can't be opened.

Answer (score 4):

You can, use CMake and generate VSx solution.

I think the project that you have seen had 2 visual studio solutions for different visual studio versions.

Update:
 Also, you can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/vspc/
or see http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ProjectConverter.htm

Comment: Thanks :)  Will check these out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution format hasn't changed significantly over the visual studio versions except the version number.
If the code itself is generic enough (not using linq, etc) then you can edit the first line of the solution file to "downgrade" the version.

VS2005 uses:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 9.00
# Visual Studio 2005
```

Comment: +1; This will be useful information to someone, though not me.  The reason I can't use this solution is that I need to check in a single version into source control, and I'd rather avoid having people check these files out indefinitely, especially because they'll check in legitimate changes to the project from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the [Prebuild project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnpb/) a try to generate needed solution files on the fly.

> Prebuild is a cross-platform XML-driven pre-build tool which allows
>   developers to easily generate project files for major IDE's and .NET
>   development tools including: Visual Studio .NET 2002, 2003, 2005, 2008,  2010
>   SharpDevelop, MonoDevelop, NAnt and Autotools.

Comment: Looks interesting.  I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

May be it is not what you ask about, but you can convert you project into `nmake` target

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to create separate solutions (for 2010 and 2008), and include existing projects to different solutions. Create new projects in VS2008, and then add them to VS2010 solution.

Comment: Will try this out when I get a chance.

Answer (score -1):

You may need something like `round-tripping`

> Round-tripping is the ability to use a current or previous version of Visual Studio to target a platform that is supported by both versions of VS. For example, with round-tripping, you can open projects from a previous version of VS in a newer IDE without the need for conversion, thus allowing you to work side-by-side on old and upgraded projects.

Read [more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/why-does-visual-studio-2010-convert-my-projects.aspx)

Comment: But that article says it's explicitly not supported by VS?

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Great article.  Unfortunately it tells me that everyone else's answer is correct: I really need two solutions.